# How to add results from a JSON stored in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

How to add results from a JSON stored in POSTGRESQL?

However, an error is returned in the query.

The "amount" field is in string format. Is there anything you can convert to an integer and add it SUM?

I'm doing it this way.

```
Transactions.objects.filter(id=id, metadata__metadata__deleted='false')\
                                                                    .annotate(amount=RawSQL("metadata->>%s", ("amount", )))\
                                                                    .aggregate(amountTotal=Sum('amount'))
```

---

```
Transactions.objects.filter(id=id, metadata__metadata__deleted='false')\
                                                                    .annotate(l=RawSQL("data->>%s", (int("amount"),)))\
                                                                    .aggregate(clicked=Sum('l'))
```

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column reference "metadata" is
>   ambiguous LIBERTYBLUE | LINE 1: SELECT SUM("l") FROM (SELECT
>   (metadata->>'amount') AS "l" FR...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps. But below is the approach I implemented on my project using MySQL database.

```
from django_mysql.models.fields.json import KeyTransform

Table.objects.all().annotate(amount = KeyTransform('json_key/Dictionary_key)', 'field_name')).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the feedback. It worked partly. however in the SUM an error was issued. function sum(jsonb) does not exist

Comment: @marcelo.delta did you find a fix for `function sum(jsonb) does not exist` ? Thanks